# weird USB behaviour

Tags: usb, pi-4

I've attached a usb ESC/POS thermal printer to my pi, and installed this:
https://github.com/klirichek/zj-58 as driver using its readme.

I have a python script that access the USB device with pyUsb.

The weird behaviour happens as follows:
If I start the script from the pi user, it will not work

```
An Error has occured while printing
[Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 223, in get_interface_and_endpoint
    return self._ep_info[endpoint_address]
KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usbController.py", line 32, in printTextLine
    self.dev.write(0x1, (text+'\n').encode())
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 940, in write
    intf, ep = self._ctx.setup_request(self, endpoint)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 215, in setup_request
    intf, ep = self.get_interface_and_endpoint(device, endpoint_address)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 225, in get_interface_and_endpoint
    for intf in self.get_active_configuration(device):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 236, in get_active_configuration
    self.managed_open()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 120, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 786, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 643, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 595, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usbController.py", line 103, in <module>
    usbC.printTextLine("This Is Some Text")
  File "usbController.py", line 36, in printTextLine
    raise Exception
Exception
```

When i do sudo bash, and run it, I get the following output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/OcOrder/Python $ sudo bash
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/OcOrder/Python# python usbController.py
initting dev
An Error has occured while printing
[Errno 5] Input/Output Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usbController.py", line 103, in <module>
    usbC.printTextLine("This Is Some Text")
  File "usbController.py", line 36, in printTextLine
    raise Exception
Exception
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/OcOrder/Python# exit
```

When I then return to the regular user, it suddenly works.

```
python3 usbController.py
initting dev
pi@raspberrypi:~/OcOrder/Python $
```

In the past, when I started to try to configure this setup, I've also changed some files here:

```
 # exctract from my history
 vi /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb-perms.rules
 mv /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb-perms.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules
 udevadm control --reload
 udevadm trigger
 chmod 777 /dev/ttyprintk
```

While this is a somewhat workable solution, it is not quite what I'm looking for.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to correct your script `usbController.py`.

Comment: @Ingo, any pointers as to what I should change? Since it works after doing sudo bash, it does not appear to need any changes

Comment: What USB device class does your printer have? Did you add your user to the relevant group, e.g. `lp`, `tty` or `dialout`?